# Remove row from generic datatable in C#

Tags: c#, datatable, row

I ran into a problem trying to remove a row from a datatable in C#.  The problem is that the datatable is built from SQL, so it can have any number of columns and may or may not have a primary key.  So, I can't remove a row based on a value in a certain column or on a primary key.

Here's the basic outline of what I'm doing:

```
//Set up a new datatable that is an exact copy of the datatable from the SQL table.  
newData = data.Copy();
//...(do other things)
foreach (DataRow dr in data.Rows)
{
  //...(do other things)
  // Check if the row is already in a data copy log.  If so, we don't want it in the new datatable.
  if (_DataCopyLogMaintenance.ContainedInDataCopyLog(dr))
  {
    newData.Rows.Remove(dr);
  }
}
```

But, that gives me an error message, "The given DataRow is not in the current DataRowCollection".  Which doesn't make any sense, given that newData is a direct copy of data.  Does anyone else have any suggestions?  The MSDN site wasn't much help.

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, you have a _copy_, but you don't have _that exact row_. If you want to remove a row from newData, you've got to reference one of the rows it contains, not a row from another table (even though it's an exact duplicate, it's still different and can't be used to remove the same row from newData).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `foreach` needs to be on the copy, not the original set. You cannot remove an object contained in collection1 from collection2.

```
foreach (DataRow dr in newData.Rows)
```

Otherwise you could use a counter to remove at an index. Something like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < data.Rows.Count; i++)
{
  if (_DataCopyLogMaintenance.ContainedInDataCopyLog(data.Rows[i]))
  {
    newData.Rows.RemoveAt(i);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what I needed.  I never saw any caveats about the datatabe.copy() method, but it makes sense that it's just a copy and doesn't reference the original rows.